# Make a pie in matplotlib from a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` that has many columns. I need to make a pie using the `users` columns and appear according to the `number` column.

```
users  number   col1  col2
user1   1        12    abc
user2   34       13    ..
user3   56       12
user4   45       ..
user5   4
user1   3
user5   11
user1   3
```

How to do the pie according to the percent that users have in the number column?So it can be clear who has the higher number as a percentage of the whole. If you need clarification ask me. Thanks

I did:

```
plt.pie(x['users'],x['number'])
```

but it says:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'user11'
```

Comment: What is wrong with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal working solution taking one column and plotting their sum userwise based on your example dataframe. It might not be the smartest way to do it though, but gives you what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1,34,56,45,4, 3, 11, 3], 
                  'users':['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5', 'user1','user5','user1']})
df1 = df.groupby(['users']).sum().reset_index()
df1 = df1.set_index('users')
plot = df1.plot.pie(y='number', figsize=(6, 6))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: The user1,user2.. is a column not an index. I can't make it work in my example.

Comment: Strange. It worked for me but still, I edited. Try out the new answer and let me know

Comment: can the existence of more columns in my dataset making things complicated?

Comment: Do you get anything when using `plot = df.plot.pie(y='number', figsize=(6, 6))`

Comment: I get a pie with all the rows of the dataset 158. Which is not what I want. The solution would be to get the sum of `number` grouped by each user.

Comment: I updated my answer taking two columns. Let me know if it answers your problem

Comment: the `sum_all` column is exactly the same with the `number` column . Keep in mind that there are more than those two columns in the dataframe. So maybe they should be mentioned what are needed in any stage.

Comment: Ok, I lost you. Plz share how your data frame looks like. Currently I am just speculating things

Comment: I have updated the dataset in the question. Note that only the 2 first columns should be considered for the pie. But I don't want to drop the others because are needed for further processes.

Comment: Ok, check the edit. You can use it similarly on your dataframe

Comment: That made it. Can you tell me why the set_index is important?

Comment: If you don't set the index to the `users`, the legends will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. By setting the index to the 'users', the legends will be directly chosen to be `users` because the default legends are the `index` column. Comment the line `df1 = df1.set_index('users')` and see the difference in the legend

Answer (score 0):

The pie function takes only 1 value for the size of each pie, and you'll have to explicitly specify the label as 'label = x['users']' you can find a more detailed understanding for the parameters [Here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) !

Therefore, your code would be like this:

```
plt.pie(x['number'],labels = x['users'])
```